# Yii Framework - How do I get a different value for a field?

Tags: php, yii

I have a table with a field called `vat_free`. So my model was created with a property `$vat_free`. Its value can be **0** or **1**.

I want my view to show **No** or **Yes**, instead of **0** or **1**. I can do it creating a getter like `getVatFree()`, but it seems like a messy solution, because then I'll have two properties to the same field, even though it would serve different purposes.

So how can I use only the original property `$vat_free`? Couldn't I modify its getter?

Comment: `<option value="1">Yes</option>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do like

```
$vat_free = YES or NO
```

but right before save this object you would override object class with `beforeSave()` method like following:

```
beforeSave(){
   if($this->vat_free = YES){
         $this->vat_free = 1
   }else{
$this->vat_free = 0;
   }
}
```

and override `afterFind()` to do the reverse(for beforeSave()) translate. But this is even messy and will not work if u do bulk save or retrieve.

I see 2 solutions.

1. Go with what you have said `getVatFree()`, this is whole purpose of OOP encapsulation.
2. Instead of making 1 or 0 in db, do Y or N values, you can use them in both places without problems.

Answer (score 4):

Creating method

```
public function getVatFreeString(){
    return $this->vat_free ? 'Yes':'No';
}
```

Is proper solution, it's not messy.

Answer (score 2):

In your model, create a new field that will be used for display purposes only.

```
class User extends CActiveRecord
{

  public $displayVatFreeFlag;

  public function rules() { ... }

  public function afterFind()
  {
     $this->displayVatFreeFlag = ($this->vat_free ? 'Yes':'No');
  }
}
```

Then, in your field, display the field as normal.

```
Vat free : <?php echo $model->displayVatFreeFlag; ?>
```